# What's the stealthiest way to knock someone out?

Tags: weapons, medicine, crime, stealth

A sneaky character needs to incapacitate someone. It's a sensitive situation, so this must be done *quickly, quietly, and reliably.*

The target is a healthy human adult. Killing the target is highly undesirable, and it's best if the target is unable to explain what happened afterwards. Ideally, the target would just instantly black out and suffer no easy-to-discover consequences (e.g. bruises).

The sneaky character is well-resourced and can obtain obscure or illegal substances if needs be, but they have to be *real* substances available today.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Something from the ACME company. Maybe an anvil. :)

Comment: This isn't about building a world.

Comment: I agree this isn't worldbuilding --- it's story smithing.  There ought to be a Stack Exchange site just for story smithing.

Comment: @JBH But there isn’t. How might we start one?

Comment: @TanzaniteDragoness visit [area51.SE].

Answer (score 3):

[Propofol](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/milk-of-amnesia-a-powerful-anaesthetic-abused-all-too-often-6258738.html) Dart gun

load a dart gun with propofol and shoot your subject, they will go out like a light and wake up like nothing happened

You can substitute a bunch of other anesthetics or barbiturates

Answer (score 3):

## Bag over head and sleeper hold

Well unless you can get your victim to eat or drink something that will first sedate them, and if safety is a priority, then a [sleeper hold / blood choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chokehold#Blood_choke) is the best bet.

## DO NOT TRY THE FOLLOWING IN REAL LIFE, NOT 100% SAFE

Standing from behind the attacker puts say their right arm over the right shoulder of the victim, up against the side of the neck. Then they bend the arm at the elbow so that the forearm comes at the left side of the neck. They then squeeze the neck **only at the sides**.

This shuts the cartoid arteries, depriving the brain of fresh oxygenated blood. The victim goes down in a few seconds.

Left hand over the mouth prevents any screaming.

## DO NOT TRY THAT IN REAL LIFE, IT IS NOT ENTIRELY SAFE

The idea is to avoid crushing the windpipe because that is extremely dangerous.

The bag over the head adds panic and confusion and while the victim **may** possibly realize what happened afterwards, it will be hard to make any coherent statement about the incident.

Answer (score 0):

Ether or Chloroform would be what instantly come to mind, but there is a slight problem.  Either one would leave a memory of having a cloth pressed over the mouth (if you are using *film Nior* methods).  I'm also sure there would be trace evidence in the victim's blood.  The evidence will be there, but it will take more time to find than a lump on the back of the skull

So how can you get a puff of ether or chloroform to the victim stealthily?  Depending on the environment your victim is in, create something that is often referred to as a "honey trap".  Something your victim is going to get face to face with.  Maybe it's a vending machine, a security scanner, or a water fountain. A hidden atomizer and *poof*, they go down.

Alternatively, you could sabotage something on your victims person.  Slip a drug laced cigarette in their pack.  Slip a mickey into a pack of gum.

Delivery methods are going to be highly dependent on environment and circumstance.  I'm focusing on the ones likely to be used on the poor rent-a-cop walking around a boring scientific facility.

An alternative could be something as simple as a traditional sap. That will leave a bruise, but contrive a water leak or some sort of slick spill in the area, and the bruise won't be questioned too much.  This one carries more risk, as head trauma is hard to predict.  Only to be used when you have limited access to the area and are in a really big hurry.

Comment: Problem with chemicals is that you have to be very careful to get the dosage right. Even trained doctors and anesthesiologists make mistakes and kill people or leave them brain dead from time to time.

Comment: @JBiggs That's always a problem when you need to "turn someone off" for a time.  Nothing is purely safe, but some methods are probably safer than others.  I figure a puff of chloroform is more likely to be safe that a blunt instrument.  Plus you can get creative with delivery methods.

Comment: ether? i thought that the oracle of delphi breathed that stuff which came from the volcano fumes.

Answer (score 0):

**Sap**.

Mafia types developed an answer to this problem a LONG time ago. Simple, low-tech, extremely effective and reliable. It's pretty simple. Usually something like powdered lead dumped into the end of a sock-like (but stronger) cloth tube. The sap can be concealed easily, deployed quickly, held in the palm of the hand without being noticed, and all you have to do is come up behind someone and swing it at their temple. Bang. It is very reliable, and because it doesn't use a solid bludgeon, it usually doesn't even leave bruises. One second they are standing there, the next, fireworks and they wake up later.

Some good info on Saps [here](http://www.donrearic.com/sap.html).

Comment: Is this reliable? That you could knock a person out every time?

Comment: "suffer no easy-to-discover consequences". Just because you wrap it in a sock does not mean it wont swell

Comment: A well desined sap will leave almost no mark. They were DESIGNED not to leave evidence behind by people who had to do a stealthy knock-out without leaving evidence for police.

Comment: @LioElbammalf Yes. With some very basic level of skill, a sap is EXTREMELY reliable.

Comment: Knocking someone unconscious with blunt trauma to the head 1) will leave a bruise/bump (that nonsense about it not leaving a mark I do not believe for a second) 2) is potentially lethal. At the very least you have given the victim a nasty concussion. So no... this is not a safe, nor a stealthy way of doing it.

Comment: @MichaelK Have you ever had to take someone down? Did you even bother doing any research before you declared that you don't believe for a minute that someone can knock a person out with a sap without leaving a mark? It used to be a STAPLE weapon for both mob enforcers and cops all over the country. Both groups had a vested interest in doing things in a way that would not leave a lot of evidence. As far as potentially lethal ANYTHING YOU DO to make someone unconscious is potentially lethal. This just happens to be easy and pretty idiot proof, unlike most drugs/chemicals.

Comment: Mob enforcers and cops also have a history of killing through the head trauma that results from beating someone into unconsciousness with heavy blows to the skull. There might not be any obvious physical evidence, but that's more because brain injury is hard to detect, as opposed to because hitting someone in the head with a heavy object makes them go to sleep with no ill effect. The injury that produces unconsciousness- bouncing the brain against the skull- is inherently a traumatic experience with very little wiggle room between 'still awake' and 'permanent damage'.